# Alter Table query in sqlite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I want to drop one of the column from my sqlite database . I apply following query for this :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;
```

but it is giving me following error:

```
near "DROP": syntax error
```

is drop column supporting in sqlite3 database. If yes then whats wrong with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using `ALTER TABLE User DROP COLUMN firstName;` just to see if it works by any chance but 
as per the Documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.com/lang.html) the only features supported are DROP TRIGGER, INDEX, TABLE and VIEW

I really doubt if DROP COLUMN is supported.

EDIT: [Here](http://sqlite.org/faq.html) at Point number 11 you can find the answer to your question which reads as follows

*SQLite has limited ALTER TABLE support that you can use to add a column to the end of a table or to change the name of a table. If you want to make more complex changes in the structure of a table, you will have to recreate the table. You can save existing data to a temporary table, drop the old table, create the new table, then copy the data back in from the temporary table.*

```
For example, suppose you have a table named "t1" with columns names "a", "b", and "c" and that you want to delete column "c" from this table. The following steps illustrate how this could be done:

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(a,b);
    INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT a,b FROM t1;
    DROP TABLE t1;
    CREATE TABLE t1(a,b);
    INSERT INTO t1 SELECT a,b FROM t1_backup;
    DROP TABLE t1_backup;
    COMMIT;
```